# How to use a installscript.qs file for creating an installer correctly

Tags: qt, installation

Using Qt Creator IDE and C++ code I created an app and put the file *Qt_Calculator.exe* into a folder named *Result* on my Windows desktop. I used *Qt Installer Framework 2.01* to make an installer for my app.

I used a CMD command as below:

```
C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\package_directory\packages\com.vendor.product\data> 
C:\Qt\QtIFW2.0.1\bin\binarycreator.exe -c 
C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\package_directory\config\config.xml -p 
C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\package_directory\packages 
C:\Users\Abbasi\Desktop\Result\Qt_Calculator.exe
```

I have a *package_directory* folder that [contains this](https://postimg.org/image/b0coc2hsp/).

The *config* folder has a *config.xml* that [contains this](https://postimg.org/image/muzzwv0y7/).

The *packages* folder has a *com.vendor.product* folder that in turn it also has two folders, *data* and *meta*. The *data* folder [contains this](https://postimg.org/image/xo0abebkx/).

The *meta* folder has four files: *installscript.qs*, *License.txt*, *package.xml* and *pageform.ui*
The *package.xml* [contains this](https://postimg.org/image/v6h02m6y3/).

And *installscript.qs* [this](https://postimg.org/image/f6ycj0l6x/).

By *installscript.qs* I want to create an installer so that it can be installed in *C:\ProgramFiles* folder and creates a shortcut of the app on my desktop.
It doesn't work well and I should change the code inside *installscript.qs* but don't know what code should be added/removed so that the installer works that way.

Have you ever used *Qt Installer Framework* to create an installer?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not shure what you problem ist. Try to show errors etc. You can try to use https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtIFW-Advanced-Setup, it automates the process of creating an installer and only needs a few qmake variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please read [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/80448/how-to-create-a-qs-file/26) thread.